# How to use CMake to create a package that installs to '/etc' and '/var'?

Tags: cmake, cpack

I've got CMake (3.02) installing to a DESTDIR when I invoke:

```
$ make -C build DESTDIR=$(pwd)/build/rootfs install
```

This results in a file layout that I'm happy with: binaries are located in the `.../build/rootfs/usr/local/bin` directory and the init scripts are in `.../build/rootfs/etc/init.d`.  To accomplish that, I used a mixture of relative and absolute paths in my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
set(CPACK_SET_DESTDIR       ON)
...
INCLUDE(CPack)
...
set(ROOTFS_BIN_DIR          bin)
set(ROOTFS_ETC_INITD_DIR    /etc/init.d)
...
INSTALL(TARGETS myDaemon DESTINATION ${ROOTFS_BIN_DIR})
INSTALL(PROGRAMS myDaemon.sh RENAME myDaemon DESTINATION ${ROOTFS_ETC_INITD_DIR})
```

With that, I think 'working', I'm trying to create a simple tarball package which will eventually become a debian package (with pre/post install/remove scripts) but when I invoke:

```
$ make -C build DESTDIR=$(pwd)/build/rootfs package
```

I'm getting errors because `cpack` is attempting to write my init scripts to the system's `/etc/init.d` directory (instead of `$(pwd)/build/rootfs/etc/init.d`).  If I wanted that, then `$sudo !!` would solve the problem. The error (replaced full path with `...`):

```
CMake Error at .../build_src/cmdServer/cmake_install.cmake:44 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot copy file
  ".../src/cmdServer/cmdServer.sh" to
  "/etc/init.d/cmdServer".
```

I'm not using a lot of `CPACK` directives: in my top level `CMakeLists.txt` file I have:

```
SET(CPACK_SET_DESTDIR ON)
SET(CPACK_GENERATOR   TGZ)
INCLUDE(CPack)
```

How can I package my init scripts correctly?

I've been referencing:
https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2008-April/020833.html
and https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2006-November/011890.html

Comment: Skip the leading slash from the `/etc/init.d` path. The documentation of the INSTALL command says: DESTINATION
Specify the directory on disk to which a file will be installed. If a full path (with a leading slash or drive letter) is given it is used directly. If a relative path is given it is interpreted relative to the value of the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX variable.

Comment: @vre If I do that, then files get installed to `{prefix directory}/usr/local/etc/init.d`. Or, maybe that's the way it should be and I'm to just move the files to the correct spot with a `postinst` script?

Comment: Does adding `set(CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX "/")` help?

Comment: @vre Yes.  Only by leaving the absolute path prefix and adding the `SET(...PACKAGING...PREFIX "/")`, the `ar` debian archive shows the files I want destined for `/etc/init.d` going into `etc/init.d`.  If the absolute prefix is dropped, however, it puts everything off `usr/local`. Thanks!